# Element animation with respect to its center using just css

Tags: html, css

I have spend hours trying to find a solution that just requires css to work. I am trying to animate a div when it is hoverd, that its height and width be reduced uniformly.

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

Above is a simple div element with the following css:

```
.a {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background: #000;
    margin: 100px 0 0 400px;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    position:fixed;
}
```

I want to reduce the height and width of the element on hover from the center using just css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `scale()` 
As per your requirement, ideally what you would want to do is to fire the `scale()` function on hover of the target element as:

```
.a {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  position: fixed;
}
.a:hover {
  transform:scale(0.7);
}
```

This css function will zoom the div element with respect to its center. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) for a complete reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scale` transformation:

```css
.a {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  position: fixed;
}
.a:hover {
  transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `:hover` [pseudoclass](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).

```
.a:hover {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

The transition on `.a` will apply as expected.